# Optimization of scrolling performance with parallax effect

Tags: html, css, sass, parallax

I have a page with two sections which are stacked over each other. The upper section has a background image with a fixed position to create a parallax effect. Because I had massive performance issues while scrolling  I had to change the layout.

From this:

```
.upper-section {

    height: 100vh;

    background: url("./img/background.png") no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.lower-section { 
    height: 100vh;
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
.upper-section {

    height: 100vh;

    overflow: hidden; // added for pseudo-element
    position: relative; // added for pseudo-element

    &::before {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        position: fixed; // instead of background-attachment
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url("./img/background.png") no-repeat fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        will-change: transform; // creates a new paint layer
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

to put the background in it's own container. My problem is that i the background image container is not inheriting the height of the upper-section container and covers the lower section too. If i change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` I get the same performance issue as before. Any idea how to fix this issue?

## UPDATE 1

To all future readers: I fixed my problem by setting the background of the lower section to white:

```
.lower-section { 
    height: 100vh;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1ue288dg/1/ Can you point to a page where this goes wrong?

Comment: The background image should only cover the upper section. The lower section should be without a background image. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hn93sqqh/

Comment: If the lower section has no background, then you see through it . https://jsfiddle.net/1ue288dg/2/

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you! This seems to do the trick.

Comment: else, it works also without pseudo: https://jsfiddle.net/1ue288dg/3/

Comment: @GCyrillus this looks like my first approach, but that's where i got the performance issue from.

Comment: Okay, i get it now :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully appreciate what the issue was. @GCyrillus Can you post that as an answer, otherwise this question will remain unanswered forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your attempt and advised from @MrLister to give an answer to the question:

As commented earlier and lost in the flow of comments , you were missing a background on `.lower-section` to hide previous one(s).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0
}

.upper-section {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.upper-section::before {
  content: ' '; 
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/700/700") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  will-change: transform;  
  z-index: -1;
}

.lower-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper-section">
  Upper section
</div>

<div class="lower-section">
  Lower section
</div>
```